# How to justify this symbol in MathType

Tags: formula, mathtype

I have a formula in MathType attached below. But I could not justify the position of $+\infty$ symbol. I want it appear just after the "${$" and aligns to the left of the second term.

Thank you for your help.

[image: Equation]

The LaTex Code:

${{R}*{1}}\left( {{x}*{pi}},{{G}*{q}},{{x}*{qj}} \right)=\,\left{ \begin{matrix}
   +\infty  & p=q  \
   \underset{l=1}{\overset{d}{\mathop \sum }}\,({{x}*{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}*{qj}}\left[ l \right])\left( 2\left( {{x}*{qj}}\left[ l \right]-{{{\bar{x}}}*{q}}\left[ l \right] \right)+({{x}*{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}*{qj}}\left[ l \right])(\left| {{G}*{q}} \right|-1)/|{{G}*{q}}| \right) & p\ne q  \
\end{matrix} \right.$

Answer (score 0):

I must use array statement instead of matrix.

LaTex Code:

[
{{R}*{1}}\left( {{x}*{pi}},{{G}*{q}},{{x}*{qj}} \right)=\,\left{ \begin{array}{@{}lc}
   +\infty  & p=q  \
   \underset{l=1}{\overset{d}{\mathop \sum }}\,({{x}*{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}*{qj}}\left[ l \right])\left( 2\left( {{x}*{qj}}\left[ l \right]-{{{\bar{x}}}*{q}}\left[ l \right] \right)+({{x}*{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}*{qj}}\left[ l \right])(\left| {{G}*{q}} \right|-1)/|{{G}*{q}}| \right) & p\ne q  \
\end{array} \right.
]